# Deleting Haxe (3.4.2) from macOS (Sierra)

Tags: macos, installation, uninstallation, haxe, macos-sierra

I installed the latest Haxe version (3.4.2) but then learned that the project I need it for requires an older version (3.1.3). Unfortunately, the installer has no uninstall option. Therefore, I manually deleted all Haxe files that the Finder search listed (including system files and hidden files).

When I now run the Haxe 3.1.3 installer, it shows that the installation was completed successfully but it seems to have installed no Haxe files and when I type "haxe" in Terminal, I receive a "command not found" result.

It seems to me that the installer does not install at all because it still discovers a remainder of the previous Haxe installation somewhere.

By the way, I also removed the following lines from /etc/environment:

```
export HAXE_STD_PATH=/usr/local/haxe/std:. # path to std + :.
export HAXE_HOME=/usr/whatever/haxe # path to haxe
export NEKOPATH=/usr/local/neko # path to neko
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try deleting all and copy the Binaries instead of the installer with

```
sudo rm -f -r /usr/local/lib/haxe
sudo cp -R yourhaxedir /usr/local/lib/haxe
```

maybe you need to change reading and writting permissions

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/haxe/haxe
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/haxe/haxelib
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/haxe/lib
```

Don't forget to set your libs directory

```
haxelib setup wherever/lib
sudo chmod 777 wherever/lib
```

the default is /usr/local/lib/haxe/lib